# punctuation between authors/editors and title in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

With the hook `\labelnamepunct` I managed to change a period to a colon after the first set of authors and the following title.
But, as in the example below, if this is an inbook, for instance, there is a period used as delimiter between the second author-title combination.

**Whats the hook for that punctuation point?**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian,german]{babel}  % last language in order will be active

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        bibstyle=authortitle,
        citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
        sorting=nyvt,   % n-umber, y-ear, v-olume, t-itle
        block=space,        % spacing between blocks: values: none (default), space, par, nbpar, ragged
        isbn=false,     % whether the fields isbn/issn/isrn
        url=false,      % affects entry types whose url information is optional
        doi=false,      % digital object identifier
        hyperref=false, % links between cites and bibliography
        ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{onebook.bib}
@inbook{woodward82,
author={Woodward, James B.},
title={The Nose},
subtitle={},
bookauthor={Woodward, Andrea},
booktitle={The Symbolic Art of Gogol},
booksubtitle={Essays on His Short Fiction},
publisher={Slavica},
address={Columbus, Ohio},
year={1982},
pages={63--87},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{onebook.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this (with a period between "... Andrea" AND "The Symbolic ...", where I want a colon to be):

[image: result of code above]

Comment: A quick fix is `\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{\ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}{}{\printnames{bookauthor}}\printunit{\labelnamepunct}}` (looks especially messy here because line breaks were removed): this will look weird however, if there is no `booktitle` (which probably should not happen anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least to ways you can fix this.

The first is a re-definition of the `bybookauthor` macro that is used to print the `bookauthor`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames{bookauthor}}%
  \printunit{\labelnamepunct}}
```

This will insert `\labelnamepunct` into the punctuation buffer, where it will remain until needed. Because of that, this solution might have unwanted side-effects, for example if no `author` is present and if the `in:` bibmacro is redefined to not print anything.

---

So we better look for something else.

As it does so often, En­rico Gre­go­rio's [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package comes in very handy here.

Load it with `\usepackage{xpatch}`

We then patch the bibliography driver for `@inbooks` to use `\labelnamepunct` after the `bookauthor` field if it is present (unfortunately we need this test to prevent this solution to have the short come mentioned above).

```
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
     {\newunit\newblock}
     {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}}
  {}
  {\typeout{failed to patch bibdriver inbook to use \labelnamepunct}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{babel} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        bibstyle=authortitle,
        citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
        ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{woodward82,
author={Woodward, James B.},
title={The Nose},
bookauthor={Woodward, Andrea},
booktitle={The Symbolic Art of Gogol},
booksubtitle={Essays on His Short Fiction},
publisher={Slavica},
address={Columbus, Ohio},
year={1982},
pages={63--87},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
     {\newunit\newblock}
     {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}}
  {}
  {\typeout{failed to patch bibdriver inbook to use \labelnamepunct}}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank You very much. Strikes me though, that there is no simple hook to that punctuation. Seems a little complicated, to simply alter some comma or period ...

Comment: @fourreux Well, `biblatex` does specify some special delimiters. Most punctuation marks are however the standard `\newunitpunct` (as is the case here), those can at times be quite hard to modify because they are inserted at a very high level (the bibliography driver). Defining a dedicated command for every single punctuation goes a bit too far.